# How to left join to a temporal table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Environment: SQL- Server

I have two tables on my SQl-Server database, a purchase table and an customer_order table. The purchase table is a temporal table stored all historical price from my supplier of an item while the customer_order stored all customer orders I have received.

```
Create table Purchase (
    Item_ID identity not null,
    Item_Name Varchar(300),
    Cost numeric,
    <Some other unrelated columns>,
    [Valid_From] datetime2 generated always as row Start,
    [Valid_To] datetime2 generated always as row End,
    period for system_time (Valid_From, Valid_To)
)
with (system_versioning = on (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.Purchase_His))

Create Table Customer_Order (
    Order_Number identity,
    Item_Id int,
    Sales_Price numeric,
    Order_Date datetime,
    <Other columns> ...
```

)

Sample data for Purchase table

| Item_ID | Item_Name | Cost | Valid_From | Valid_To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Coca-Cola 355ml | $1.00 | 20200101 00:00:00 | 20201231 23:59:59 |
| 1 | Coca-Cola 355ml | $2.00 | 20210101 00:00:00 | 20211231 23:59:59 |
| 1 | Coca-Cola 355ml | $3.00 | 20220101 00:00:00 | 20221231 23:59:59 |
| 1 | Coca-Cola 355ml | $4.00 | 20230101 00:00:00 | 99999999 23:59:59 |

For simplicity, you can assume that I only have one supplier and only selling Coca-Cola.

Sample Customer Order table

| Order_number | Item_ID | Sales_Price | Order_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | $1.10 | 20200301 |
| 1002 | 1 | $2.20 | 20210401 |
| 1003 | 1 | $3.30 | 20220401 |
| 1004 | 1 | $4.40 | 20230401 |

Now I need to join the two tables so using the item_id to get the profit margin for each order. My purposed result would be:

| Order_number | Item_ID | Sales_Price | Order_Date | Cost | Margin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 | $1.10 | 20200301 | $1.00 | $0.10 |
| 1002 | 1 | $2.20 | 20210401 | $2.00 | $0.20 |
| 1003 | 1 | $3.30 | 20220401 | $3.00 | $0.30 |
| 1004 | 1 | $4.40 | 20230401 | $4.00 | $0.40 |

Note:

1. I also need to bring in all other columns from the purchase table where the value needs to be as at the time the order being placed.
2. The Margin is calculated field.

Could this be fulfilled by using a left join statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose that item_id shall always be 1, not 1, 2, 3, and 4 in your example?

Comment: Oh yes! you are right. I just corrected it.

Comment: Also thanks to fixing my format.

Answer (score 0):

The below query may help you to get the desired result..

```
SELECT 
    co.Order_number, 
    co.Item_ID, 
    co.Sales_Price, 
    co.Order_Date, 
    p.Cost, 
    (co.Sales_Price - p.Cost) AS Margin
FROM 
    Customer_Order co
LEFT JOIN 
    Purchase FOR SYSTEM_TIME ALL p 
    ON co.Item_ID = p.Item_ID 
    AND co.Order_Date BETWEEN p.Valid_From AND p.Valid_To
```

Answer (score 0):

@MukeshArora's answer is good if you want the entire (or most of) the history table anyway. But if you only want a small number of rows, it's more efficient to use the `AS OF date` syntax.

Unfortunately, the syntax does not allow using an outer reference via `APPLY`. You can get around this restriction by using an inline Table Valued Function

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetPurchaseAtDate (
  @Item_Id bigint,
  @Date datetime2
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN

SELECT
    p.*
FROM
    dbo.Purchase FOR SYTEM_TIME AS OF @Date AS p
WHERE
    p.Item_ID = @Item_ID;
```

Now you can just `APPLY` it

```sql
SELECT
    co.Order_number, 
    co.Item_ID, 
    co.Sales_Price, 
    co.Order_Date, 
    p.Cost, 
    (co.Sales_Price - p.Cost) AS Margin
FROM 
    dbo.Customer_Order AS co
OUTER APPLY
    dbo.GetPurchaseAtDate(co.Item_ID, co.Order_Date) AS p;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/2JI2y-ME)